# ActiveMQ 5.x to Artemis Migration Approach

Tags: apache-camel, activemq-artemis

We are in a plan of migration from 5.x to the newest version (i.e. ActiveMQ Artemis) and we need a couple of clarifications if any one has done or used Camel as client application.

We are currently connecting via **Camel ActiveMQ** component and I don't see any Artemis component as such in Camel. We do have other components such as JMS, SJMS, AMQP. Any thoughts on which one to go for and recommended for connecting to Artemis? I think I have options of using **core, AMQP** protocols in new version if want to go away with OpenWire. If core protocol is intended for applications migrating from JBoss, good to go with AMQP component which underneath uses AMQP protocol and conforms to JMS specifications?

Comment: You've got too many questions here. You need to focus your question down to a single issue (e.g. just config migration or just Camel component migration).

Comment: Noted , changed to first understand the better ways to migrate client applications using camel when we migrate to artemis.  For config & data migration , will post another discussion. Thanks.

Comment: Sometimes two different questions are better than one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no Camel component specifically for ActiveMQ Artemis like there is for ActiveMQ 5.x. However, ActiveMQ Artemis supports the OpenWire protocol which is what the ActiveMQ Camel component uses so your client applications don't necessarily need to change.

If you *want* to change your Camel applications then you can use the JMS or SJMS Camel components with any of the following JMS client implementations:

- OpenWire JMS (shipped with ActiveMQ 5.x)
- core JMS (shipped with ActiveMQ Artemis)
- Qpid JMS (independent JMS client implementation using AMQP)

You can also use the AMQP Camel component with the Qpid JMS client if you like.

Which component you use is entirely dependent on your specific use-case. You haven't really provided any specifics about your use-case so it's impossible to provide guidance there. You'll need to evaluate the pros and cons of each approach and decide for yourself.

Comment: Thank you. If I stay as-is on Open Wire , then shall I get all new features of Artemis ( for ex  : As I am not going to use new client jars any concerns on client side load balancing or fail over) ?   I will further read on other options like core/qpid JMS first in-details if need to enhance client applications.. .  Btw , use case is we have spring boot based micro services talking to each other over messaging deployed on K8S  ( No XA or advanced bridges , just point to point messaging )

Comment: If you're using the `failover` schema in your OpenWire client's URL you should still get failover and load-balancing as described in [the documentation](https://activemq.apache.org/failover-transport-reference). For what it's worth, such a high-level description of your use-case still isn't sufficient to give any specific recommendations about which client to use. It's so generic any client should suffice.

Comment: If my answer addressed your question please mark it as correct to help others who run into this same issue in the future. Thanks!

Comment: Can I say then difference between JMS/SJMS and AMQP components in camel are mainly w.r.to the underlying protocol how client connect to server  ( AMQP uses AMQP protocol , JMS/SJMS uses TCP )  ? Then rest of of it depends on what client jars am going to use

Comment: The difference is the *wire* protocol and the underlying jars. All the protocols use TCP as the *transport* protocol. The OpenWire JMS client uses the OpenWire protocol. The core JMS client uses the core protocol. The Qpid JMS client uses the AMQP protocol.